# f:convertDateTime doesn`t convert all Date in h:inputText

Tags: java, jsf-2, converters

I want change Date with **h:inputText** with:
`<h:inputText value="#{backbean.entity.time}">

  <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="Atlantic/Canary" />
 </h:inputText>`

In server my TimeZone are `Europe/Madrid`, problem are when I only change hour this return  hour converter to my TimeZone but if I put in hour 23 it`s return 00 but doesn´t change day.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it does not create any problem. It updates the date as well as the time according to the timezone. Try the following code:

```
<h:form>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.today}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="Atlantic/Canary" /> 
</h:inputText>
<br/>
<h:commandButton action="#{testController.submit()}" value="Submit"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: But do you try write 01/01/2013 23:50 in 'testController.today' should return 02/01/2013 00:50.

Comment: It´s OK i don´t why if Date is @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) doesn´t change